# Appendix titles not aligned in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, appendices

I have a problem with the placement of Appendix titles in the TOC. I use the appendix package with titletoc option. The following code

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[title,titletoc]{appendix} 

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents 

\chapter{some chapter}

\begin{subappendices}

\section{Short title}
\section{This is a very long title that reaches the right end of the separable}
\section{Long title}

\end{subappendices}

\chapter{some other chapter}

\begin{subappendices}
\section{short title in only 1 line}
\section{much longer title that will be displayed over two lines rather than just 1}
\section{short title in only 1 line}
\end{subappendices}

\end{document}
```

produces the following TOC:

[image]

As you can see, the 1.A, 1.B and 1.C are not aligned (possibly because of the word "separable" which is too long. Similar things happen for the second block, where 2.B is not aligned.

How can I fix this apart from changing the titles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a suggestion without package `appendix`.

The section command `\section` is in `scrreprt` declared as

```
\DeclareSectionCommand[%
  style=section,%
  level=1,%
  indent=\z@,%
  beforeskip=-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex,%
  afterskip=2.3ex \@plus.2ex,%
  tocstyle=section,%
  tocindent=1.5em,%
  tocnumwidth=2.3em%
]{section}
```

You can declare a new section command on the same level as `\section` but with a different `tocnumwidth`.

```
    \documentclass[numbers=noenddot]{scrreprt}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

    \DeclareNewSectionCommand[
        style=section,
        level=1,
        indent=0pt,
        beforeskip=-3.5ex plus -1ex minus -.2ex,
        afterskip=2.3ex plus .2ex,
        tocindent=1.5em,
        tocnumwidth=7em,
        counterwithin=chapter,
        font=\usekomafont{section},
    ]{subappendix}

    \makeatletter
    \AtBeginDocument{\let\toclevel@subappendix\toclevel@section}
    \makeatother

    \renewcommand\thesubappendix{\thechapter.\Alph{subappendix}}
    \renewcommand\subappendixformat{\appendixname~\thesubappendix\autodot\quad}
    \renewcommand\addsubappendixtocentry[2]{%
        \addtocentrydefault{subappendix}{\appendixname~#1}{#2}%
    }

    \newenvironment{subappendices}{\let\section\subappendix}{}

    \begin{document}
    \tableofcontents 
    \chapter{some chapter}
    \begin{subappendices}
        \section{Short title}
        \section{This is a very long title that reaches the right end of the separable}
        \section{Long title}
    \end{subappendices}

    \chapter{some other chapter}
    \begin{subappendices}
        \section{short title in only 1 line}
        \section{much longer title that will be displayed over two lines rather than just 1}
        \section{short title in only 1 line}
    \end{subappendices}

    \chapter{some other chapter}
    \subappendix{short title in only 1 line}
    \subappendix{much longer title that will be displayed over two lines rather than just 1}
    \subappendix{short title in only 1 line}
    \end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but this solution does not work for me. I get an "! Undefined control sequence.
l.4     \DeclareNewSectionCommand" error. Potentially, my KOMA script version is too old?

Comment: Which KOMA-Script version do you use? Current version on CTAN is 3.19a. I have tested the code with version 3.16 [2015/02/07] too.  AFAIR command `\DeclareNewSectionCommand` was indroduced in version 3.15.

Comment: That probably exlpains the issues. Apparently I am using version 3.12. As this is part of my PhD thesis which is near completion, I am somewhat reluctant to update the KOMA script version right now as I am afraid that things will break.